# What is the point of a 100Mbit router that has 802.11ac Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, gigabit-ethernet, 802.11ac

I saw a few routers on the market that has 10/100 Mbit speed on cable and a 802.11ac Wi-Fi that is capable for gigabit speed. What you can use that speed when the 100Mbit cable connection will be a bottleneck? Is my logic wrong somewhere?

Take the [NETGEAR R6100](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/r6100.aspx#tab-techspecs) for example:

[image: NETGEAR R6100 specs]

Comment: By cable do you mean your local Ethernet connection or the connection to your ISP?

Comment: @slhck Both. Does it matter? Or, are you trying to say that the speed through the WAN port is gigabit but 100 Mbit through the LAN ports? Take the [Netgear R6100](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/r6100.aspx) as an example for my question.

Comment: Well, it certainly matters, since your WAN speed will rarely exceed 100 MBit/s these days, so it's fine to "just" have a 10/100 port there. But if you have Gigabit-capable WiFi and only 10/100 LAN, then clearly this is a bad design decision.

Comment: @slhck Well, according to the [specs](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/r6100.aspx#tab-techspecs) that is what happening here.

Answer (score 2):

> What you can use that speed when the 100Mbit cable connection will be
>   a bottleneck? Is my logic wrong somewhere?

Your assumption is that the main use of these Wi-Fi routers would be to only access the actual cable data connection. When in many cases, the Wi-Fi connection could—and would—be shared among devices on the local LAN. Meaning if I have a desktop and laptop sharing the same Wi-Fi then the benefit is that my Wi-Fi connection speed between the computer and laptop would be near gigabit speeds. Which would be great for a local Wi-Fi LAN.

Comment: By cable the OP meant Ethernet. Not the actual Internet or WAN connection. It's quite common for routers to only feature a 10/100 switched Ethernet. At least that's what I assume they're saying. Clarification from the OP would be good.

Comment: Yes, that point is still valid! Let's see what the OP says :)

Comment: @slhck There are many ISPs that provide Internet connection that exceed 100 MBit/s and there is a use for it e.g. file transfer to a torrent server or a private remote server. I just don't get the point of a router like the Netgear one above that provides fast Wi-Fi you cannot take advantage of (as I see in the specs, all ports of it are 100Mbit/s), except for the use JakeGould wrote but is that use case such a big market that **there are routers just for this**?